# How to execute maven plugin execution directly from command line?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a plugin (antrun) with an execution configured which has an id and is not bound to any phase. Can I execute this execution directly from the command line?

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>my-execution</id>
      ...
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

An run it with something like:

```
mvn my-execution
```

or at least

```
mvn magicplugin:execute -DexecutionId=my-execution
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a single Maven plugin execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779369/run-a-single-maven-plugin-execution)

Answer (score 160):

This functionality has been [implemented](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=commitdiff;h=ee7dbab69dd87d219031b0715105527cdbf12639;hp=cd52e5b51e8e986b6daea8c0b56dd61968410695) as [MNG-5768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768), and is available in Maven 3.3.1.

The change will:

> extend direct plugin invocation syntax to allow optional @execution-id parameter, e.g., org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.0:process@executionId.

So, in your case:

```
mvn antrun:run
```

uses the `default-cli` execution ID, and:

```
mvn antrun:run@my-execution
```

uses the execution configured in your pom.

Comment: From the artifact ID "maven-antrun-plugin" how do we know that it is just "antrun" that should be used in `mvn antrun:run`?

Comment: @mks-d see [`pluginGroups`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups) for why `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin` can be referred to as `antrun`.

Comment: @Joe thanks, on top of plugin groups there is also the [Plugin Prefix Resolution](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) mechanism apparently...

Answer (score 89):

The most direct means of executing your maven plugin is to specify the plugin goal directly on the command line.

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal
```

More information at: [Development guide for Maven plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html)

Comment: But how can I run exactly "default-cli" execution? If there are several executions in the plugin definition.

Comment: I was fighting to get a Spring Boot Jasypt utility plugin to run, and for whatever reason, the only way I could get it to get recognized by Maven was by following the advice above. Just specifying the goal directly (`mvn jasypt:encrypt ...`) wasn't enough. Thanks @dimitri-dewaele.

Comment: The question asked for running a specific execution; your answer will run all executions configured for a goal.

Comment: How do you add configuration ?

Answer (score 17):

What you're looking for is captured in [Default+Plugin+Execution+IDs](https://web.archive.org/web/20150504113922http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Default+Plugin+Execution+IDs) but to my knowledge currently not supported. However, according to the comments of [MNG-3401](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3401) (read them until the end):

> for mojos invoked directly from the
>   command line, you can supply
>   configuration from the POM using the
>   executionId: 'default-cli' like this:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>   <executions>
>     <execution>
>       <id>default-cli</id>
>       <configuration>
>         <descriptorRefs>
>           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>           <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
>         </descriptorRefs>
>       </configuration>
>     </execution>
>   </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> This should work in Maven 2.2.0 and
>   3.x.

Maybe this will be enough for you.

Comment: that was not exactly the question event if your answer is correct ;).