# Run a single Maven plugin execution?

Tags: maven, testing, maven-3, maven-plugin

I thought I was an experienced Maven user, but I am having a mental block on how to do this!

I've been able to use the Maven sql plugin to drop, create, and install a schema in a database via plugin executions I've defined and bound to the `pre-integration-test` phase.

However, now I'd like to use that same sql plugin to insert some sample data whenever I want from the command line -- that is, not bound to any lifecycle goal.  There are a few different sets of sample data, so I'd like to define a few different executions.

But is there a way to run one of these executions from the command line by using the execution ID perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute maven plugin execution directly from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166538/how-to-execute-maven-plugin-execution-directly-from-command-line)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

As noted in [How to execute maven plugin execution directly from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166538/how-to-execute-maven-plugin-execution-directly-from-command-line), this
functionality has been [implemented](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=commitdiff;h=ee7dbab69dd87d219031b0715105527cdbf12639;hp=cd52e5b51e8e986b6daea8c0b56dd61968410695) as [MNG-5768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768), and is available in Maven 3.3.1.

The change will:

> extend direct plugin invocation syntax to allow optional @execution-id parameter, e.g., org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.0:process@executionId.

So, as long as you give your execution an id:

```
mvn sql:execute@specific-execution-id
```

uses the execution configured in your pom.

Answer (score 49):

> But is there a way to run one of these executions from the command line by using the execution ID perhaps?

No, [not possible](https://web.archive.org/web/20180416084901/https://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Invoke-a-plugin-from-command-line-and-specifing-an-execution-id-td97166.html). What is possible though is to define **"a"** configuration to be used when the plugin is invoked from the command line using the "special" `default-cli` execution id:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  ...
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-cli</id>
      <configuration>
        ...
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    ...
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And simply call `mvn sql:execute`.

See below for the details (from the [Maven 2.2.0 Release Notes](http://maven.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/release-notes.html)):

> - [MNG-3401](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3401) - Starting in Maven 2.2.0,
>   goals invoked directly from the
>   command line can be configured in the
>   POM separately from other plugin
>   invocations using a special
>   `executionId` called `default-cli`.
>   Where previously, all configurations
>   for command-line goals had to go in
>   the plugin-level configuration, Maven
>   2.2.0 allows command-line-specific configurations to be separated into
>   their own `<execution>`. For more
>   information, see the [Guide to Default
>   Execution IDs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html).

Comment: I bet you could achieve what you want by using two different profiles

Comment: This answer is now outdated with current versions of Maven. See the answer provided by @Joe