# Errors using Maven Mojo sql:execute

Tags: postgresql, maven, sql-maven-plugin

TL;DR version: I want to be able to use the Maven Mojo SQL Plugin to create/drop any given table in my DB schema (or load data for those tables) at will via the `mvn` command-line.  How?

---

I'm a long-time Java developer, but for the most part I've been living in an `ant`-based world.  I like the power and explicitness of `ant`, and the control that it gives me over everything.  However, in my new job, there's a push to use `maven`.  So I've decided to learn it using a project I'm working on at home.

One of the things that I have set up on a different personal project is the ability to completely set up and tear down my Postgres database from `ant` on the command line.  I can slice and dice any table, sequence, and integration test data that I please, individually or in concert.  Sure, it means that I have about a gajillion `ant` targets, but it works very well.  I like this; it has served me quite well over the years.

In researching how to accomplish this in Maven over the weekend, I found the [Mojo SQL Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/).  After looking at the [usage page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/usage.html) (and I use that term loosely, as it's really just a single semi-example with no explanations) and the [example page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/examples/execute.html), I was able to come up with some changes to my `pom.xml` file.  I fixed some obvious typos in the example (postgressql), and referenced the [PostgreSQL JDBC page](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/connect.html) to make sure I had the JDBC connection string correct.  I'll paste all of the `pom.xml` (modified to protect the guilty) below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.CR7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>8.3-606.jdbc4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp</url>
                    <settingsKey>myapp</settingsKey>
                    <!--all executions are ignored if -Dmaven.test.skip=true-->
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-db-before-test-if-any</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- need another database to drop the targeted one -->
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/template1</url>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>drop database myapp</sqlCommand>
                            <!-- ignore error when database is not avaiable -->
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>create-db</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/template1</url>
                            <!-- no transaction -->
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>create database myapp</sqlCommand>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>create-schema</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>src/main/sql/create_person.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>create-data</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
                            <fileset>
                                <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>src/test/sql/person_data.sql</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- drop db after test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>drop-db-after-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/template1</url>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <sqlCommand>drop database myapp</sqlCommand>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, since I haven't created the database, it doesn't show up in a `\l` on the PG command-line:

```
[mike@mike myapp]$ psql template1
Welcome to psql 8.3.5, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
       \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help with psql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

template1=# \l
        List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding 
-----------+----------+----------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8
 template0 | postgres | UTF8
 template1 | postgres | UTF8
(3 rows)
```

Thus, when I run `mvn sql:execute`, I expect my database to get created...Or at least not to fail on the `drop-db-before-test-if-any` task since that is set to continue on error.  But of course:

```
[mike@mike myapp]$ mvn sql:execute
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) @ myapp ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.667s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 05 20:22:17 CST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on project myapp: FATAL: database "myapp" does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The error page mentioned on the last line there isn't helpful; it just tells me that a plugin caused the error, not Maven itself.

So let's run it with the `-X` switch.  I'll just post the interesting part of the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on project myapp: FATAL: database "myapp" does not exist -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on project myapp: FATAL: database "myapp" does not exist
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: FATAL: database "myapp" does not exist
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.execute(SqlExecMojo.java:618)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "myapp" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:444)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:99)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:124)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:386)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.getConnection(SqlExecMojo.java:899)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sql.SqlExecMojo.execute(SqlExecMojo.java:612)
    ... 21 more
```

But, but, but...`<onError>continue</onError>`!

So, to the questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?  Is it my expectations, or my code?
2. You'll notice that I have a `create-person.sql` file.  I know from the examples that I can have multiple files there, such as `create-address.sql`.  But in `ant`, I have the ability to create the `address` table separately from the `person` table, so long as I perform the ant tasks keeping in mind the order of referential integrity.  Is something like that possible with `maven`?  If so, how?

Sorry for the verbosity, and thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but you might find this plugin I started writing useful: https://github.com/adrianboimvaser/postgresql-maven-plugin. It's still in an early stage and lacks documentation, but mostly works. I already released version 0.1 to Maven Central. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute
>   ***(default-cli)***

`default-cli` is the special `executionId` when the plugin is invoked from command-line. See [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html).

You have bound all the sql plugin execution to maven lifecycle phases, but you are trying to invoke the plugin directly.

`mvn test` should work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779369/run-a-single-maven-plugin-execution) is a related SO discussion.

Comment: Well that's thoroughly unfortunate that Maven doesn't allow me to act as I previously did in Ant, but thanks for the information.