# Maven assembly dependent on assembly?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to create an assembly which depends on the output of the built-in assembly `jar-with-dependencies`. The resulting assembly is specific to an architecture.

E.g. I want to create a ZIP which contains the JAR output by `jar-with-dependencies` plus a script file and a library directory.

I have tried the following. In the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/main/assembly/linux64.xml</descriptor>
      <descriptor>src/main/assembly/windows64.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>es.entrees.BoxOffice</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then the descriptor files. One of them:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>linux64</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    ...
  </depdendencySets>
</assembly>
```

But the custom descriptors are run first, while the output from `jar-with-dependencies` is not there yet.

Should I use submodules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have 2 executions for `maven-assembly-plugin`:

- The first one, bound to the `prepare-package` phase, will create the `jar-with-dependencies`.
- The other one, bound to the `package`, will create the zip file.

In the build lifecycle, `prepare-package` phase is run before the `package` phase so this ensures that the JAR is built before the ZIP. Also, it documents the fact that creating the JAR *prepares* the final packaging, which is the ZIP file.

Sample `pom.xml` would be:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>es.entrees.BoxOffice</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>make-zip</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/linux64.xml</descriptor>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/windows64.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With the following, running Maven with `mvn clean install` will correctly create the ZIP.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the default execution is... Would it be possible to only run the execution we've configured, without compiling, invoking tests, etc?

Comment: @clapas You can refer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3779369/1743880).