# Run Maven goal only in parent POM by activation

Tags: maven

I am working on integrating a plugin into a multi-module project.

I am using a 3rd party plugin that essentially needs to only by run from the parent project (based on my understanding and usage of it). I tried to accomplish this by using a [*profile*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), like so:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-my-guy</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myproject-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>runThing</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <inherited>false</inherited>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have several `<inherited>false</inherited>`, but if I run `mvn help:all-profiles` I can still see this profile in every single module. If I run my `mvn package -P run-my-guy` I see this get executed in every single subproject. I want the ability to activate this and I do not want it to be on by default.

If I try to add it the `<build>` section, like this:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproject-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>runThing</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Here, I also have a few `<inherited>false</inherited>`, just to try and enforce that the plugin and the execution are not inherited. However, whenI run the `package` phase, or anything that includes that phase, the `runThing` goal is included.

How do I run a goal only by activation (like profile or some other feature, or just by explicitly running the goal) and only in the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in an answer for ["Run a single Maven plugin execution?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778436/627727), it is now possible (since Maven 3.3.1) to specify an execution Id for a direct goal invocation.

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproject-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <executions>
        <id>myproject-exec-id</id>    <!-- note the execution Id -->
        <execution>
          <phase>none</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>runThing</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And then invoking the goal from the command line uses the optional `@executionId` parameter:

```
mvn myproject:runThing@myproject-exec-id
```