# How to configure mvn dependency:analyze in the pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, configuration, dependencies

I'd like to use `mvn dependency:analyze` from the command line to check manually for dependencies problems. The problem is that I couldn't find a way to configure the behavior in the `pom.xml`. All parameters must be supplied in the command line.

So I must always use

```
mvn dependency:analyze -DignoreNonCompile
```

What I'm missing is a way to set the `ignoreNonCompile` in the `pom.xml` in the plugin configuration.

Something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>analyze</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>analyze</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But this don't work.

If I use

```
<goal>analyze-only</goal>
```

then the plugin is run during the build, and the configuration is used. But I don't want to have it run in the build, only manually requested. And running manually won't honor the parameter.

I could set a property in the `pom.xml` named `ignoreNonCompile`, but this will set this parameter in the build and running manually.

Is there a way to configure only the behavior of `mvn dependency:analyze`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting your configuration inside an `<execution>` block. This means that the configuration will only be bound to that specific execution; however, when invoking on the command line `mvn dependency:analyze`, it won't invoke that execution. Instead, it will invoke the plugin with a default execution using the default global configuration.

[`ignoreNonCompile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#ignoreNonCompile) is a valid configuration element for that plugin. You must use

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you don't want to define a global configuration for all executions like the above, you can keep your execution-specific configuration, but you need to tell Maven [to explicitely run that execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779369/run-a-single-maven-plugin-execution) with:

```
mvn dependency:analyze@analyze
```

where `analyze` is the execution id:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>analyze</id>  <!-- execution id used in Maven command -->
            <goals>
                <goal>analyze</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't new that with executions, thanks. Can I name the id anything?

Comment: @Asturio Yes, the id can be anything you want. (well probably restricted alphabet letters :D)

Comment: I believe you may also use 'default-cli' (stands for Default Command Line Interface) as the execution ID. Then if you run `mvn dependency:analyze` Maven will pick up the configuration from that execution by default. This might be a good option if you know that you'll always want the same config when running from the command line.