# Run custom execution in Maven before version 3.3.1

Tags: maven, plugins, execution

is it possible to run a single execution of a custom maven plugin before version 3.3.1?
`groupid:artifactid:goal@id` does only work from version 3.3.1 upwards. So how can I target a single execution id without using phases?

Comment: As answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779369/run-a-single-maven-plugin-execution, not possible in the general case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a single Maven plugin execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779369/run-a-single-maven-plugin-execution)