# CodeQL Java Analysis - missing parameters

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, pom.xml, codeql

for various reasons I decided to set an environment variable in IntelliJ for the output directory defined in pom.xml.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-files-on-build</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
>                           <outputDirectory>${PROJECT_OUTPUT}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
                                    <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Unfortunately, CodeQL Analysis throws following error:

```
 Error: 8-02 04:52:22] [autobuild] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:copy-resources (copy-files-on-build) on project PROJECT: The parameters 'outputDirectory' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:copy-resources are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
  [2023-08-02 04:52:22] [autobuild] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:copy-resources (copy-files-on-build) on project PROJECT: The parameters 'outputDirectory' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:copy-resources are missing or invalid
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

An absolute path leads to no errors and performs the analysis as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably multiple approaches to solve this:

- If this `copy-files-on-build` execution is only relevant for your local build, you could either

  - remove `<phase>package</phase>` and manually invoke the plugin when building locally, see [Run a single Maven plugin execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3779369)
  - or, move this configuration to a [Maven build profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), and either manually activate it when building locally, with `mvn --activate-profiles ...` (respectively `mvn -P ...`), or [deactivate it when running CodeQL](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#deactivating-a-profile)
- Specify the `PROJECT_OUTPUT` value with `mvn "-DPROJECT_OUTPUT=..." ...` when running CodeQL

If you want to use one of the approaches which requires a custom `mvn` command for CodeQL, you will have to use the "[advanced setup](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-advanced-setup-for-code-scanning#configuring-advanced-setup-for-code-scanning-with-codeql)" for GitHub code scanning, and there remove the autobuild step and instead [manually specify the `mvn` build command](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-the-codeql-workflow-for-compiled-languages#adding-build-steps-for-a-compiled-language). You can take for example a look at how the [Gson CodeQL workflow](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/gson-parent-2.10.1/.github/workflows/codeql-analysis.yml) specifies a custom `mvn` command to execute.