# Maven assembly plugin: prerequisite but not bind

Tags: maven

I know I can bind the assembly plugin to a "package" phase of the project but I want something different:

- When I run `mvn package` it would execute without assembly
- When I run `mvn assembly:single` it would execute the `package` phase first.

I know I can do `mvn package assembly:single` manually but this is verbose and error prone: if I edit the code and forget to put "package" into `mvn assembly:single`, this would generate **the old version of the code** in the assembly, without compiling the changed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running from CLI `mvn package assembly:single` you <strike>must</strike> (see update) provide the required properties for the [single](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) goal which explains why would you say that it is error prone.

But, if you add the following plugin definition to your pom under build plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <phase>never</phase> <!-- or undefined -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
           ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When running `mvn clean package` the assembly plugin won't run the single goal because it is not binded to any phase.

When running `mvn clean package assembly:single`, after the package phase is done the assembly:single will be run with the configuration from your pom [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169340/679982) it's execution id is `default-cli`.

#### update

To correct myself, if running from CLI, the `executions` tag is not only unnecessary but even [semantically incorrect](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Build_Plugins) to use.

Just for the reference, with this plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
           <descriptor>path/to/descriptor</descriptor>
    </configuration>            
</plugin>
```

the command `mvn assembly:single` is equivalent to command `mvn assembly:single -Ddescriptor=path/to/descriptor`. When run it outputs to console:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (default-cli) @ fm-js ---
```

The first definition is useful if you want to use the plugin both from command line and during some phase with different configurations.

As to your question, exactly as you asked, IMHO, it is not possible without reprogramming the plugin. My suggestion is in non-portable or portable form, respectively:

- wrap the command `mvn package assembly:single` in a shell script
- [write](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) a Groovy script with [gmaven-mojo plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.maven/gmaven-mojo/1.0) that summons the command `mvn package assembly:single`

Comment: 1. Why not just say that what I ask is impossible in Maven and I have to specify both parameters? 2. The `<execution>` clause is unnecessary . I also edited the question to clarify the "error-prone" part

Comment: 1. Agree. AFAIK, the command mvn assembly:single cannot trigger any phase without reprogramming the plugin. Ergo, as good as impossible :)) 2. thanks for mentioning