# Multiple java version in maven build

Tags: java, maven-3, gigaspaces

I am working on one of the modules of a multi-module project. I am developing a java plugin to deploy my gigaspace application in `pre-integration-test` phase in maven.

The build happens on Teamcity and current `JAVA_HOME` points to Java 6 on which whole repository is built. Now, when deploying the application in `pre-integration-test` phase, it needs Java 7 because it uses some 3rd party libraries which were compiled in Java 7.

Is there any way I can somehow use Java 7 for deploying my application in `pre-integration-test` phase, but use Java 6 for compilation?

Comment: this is probably impossible.

Comment: Could splitting the project into two modules be the solution?

Comment: @slartidan....how would that work ?? lets say if i split it and move all my integaration tests in a separate module and aplication can be deployed in pre-integration-phase of this project, so how do i proceed now ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not straightforward. If you look at the plugin goal that gets associated with the lifecycle phase named `pre-integration-test`, then perhaps you can control its *execution* configuration:

```
    <plugin>
          ...
          <execution>                                                               
            <id>...</id>                                            
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>                                             
            <goals>                                                                 
              <goal>...</goal>                                              
            </goals>                                                                
            <configuration>                                                         
              <source>1.7</source>                                                  
              <target>1.7</target>                                                  
            </configuration>                                                        
          </execution>                                                              
        </executions>  
   </plugin>
```

I haven't tried it myself. Also, see another somewhat similar [question and its answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609058/what-references-the-id-value-of-a-maven-plugin-execution). It's also useful to run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see what is going on.

Comment: I myself have created the plugin, i dont have any source or target configurations here

Comment: oh. Then maybe you can use [parameters in your mojo configuration](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) and fork appropriate Java Runtime? (you can use any names for those configuration options, not necessarily `source` and `target`)

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to generate JAVA 6 bytecode, then you can use JAVA 7 (JAVA_HOME points to JAVA 7) for the whole lifecycle that include integration tests, but configure the maven-compiler-plugin with the version 1.6:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```